# SSRS: Footnote automatically appear in page footer of correct page

Tags: reporting-services, pagination, ssrs-2008, footer, footnotes

Our dashboard report has four sections. Each section shows the summary/group headers, with the (very large) detail row section hidden by default, with a ToggleItem "drilldown" on each heading.

Several sections have footnotes. Right now these are coded to appear in the footer of pages 1 and 2 of the printout, which is correct if none of the detail sections are expanded. However, if you expand section 1 and 2, the footnotes for section 2 and 3 stay on pages 1 and 2, while the referenced text moves to pages 3 and 5 respectively.

I know if you use footnotes in some products (e.g., Word™), the notes move to the correct page as the referenced text moves around. Is there a way to code footnotes in SSRS so they behave "intelligently" when the content drastically changes size?

Answer (score 0):

Just to ensure, you are working with [page footers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156326%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx), right ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Globals collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216.aspx) in the expression. `Globals!PageNumber` shows the current page number, `Globals!OverallTotalPages` for total pages

Comment: That might work... that would let us code the footnote to display certain things depending on what page is rendering. How would we tell which sections are rendering on a particular page?

Comment: @EinsteinX.Mystery you can try it yourself and you'll see if the page numbers are correct. In the footnote of the page, right click `Expression`, type `=Globals.PageNumber & " of " & Globals.TotalPages`, click ok. if `=` is given in the beginning then no need to add it.